# sed - why this does not work?

Tags: sed

I'm just trying to replace a setting in a php.ini file using a bash script.

This is my case:

I have a very specific setting and the default is:

```
;date.timezone =
```

Now, I'm trying to replace this by `sed` to this:

```
date.timezone = "America/Mexico_City"
```

And the command that I'm trying to use is this:

```
sed -i '/^;date\.timezone[[:space:]]=.*$/date.timezone = "America/Mexico_City"' php.ini
```

But I get this:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 35: extra characters after command
```

I don't really know why but if I leave just a character it works (not the expected way but it doesn't return an error). Example:

```
sed -i '/^;date\.timezone[[:space:]]=.*$/d' php.ini
```

This just removes the line `;date.timezone =`

I'm really new to sed and I'd really appreciate any help.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to **s**ubstitute one pattern for another, so you need to use the sed `s` command, of the form

```
's/pattern/replacement/'
```

Also, you need to escape any `/` characters within the pattern or replacement strings (in your case `"America\/Mexico_City"`). So

```
sed 's/^;date\.timezone[[:space:]]=.*$/date.timezone = "America\/Mexico_City"/'
```

Alternatively, you can avoid escaping slashes by using an different pattern-replacement delimiter such as `s#pattern#replacement#` e.g.

```
sed 's#^;date\.timezone[[:space:]]=.*$#date.timezone = "America/Mexico_City"#'
```